# Upload Strategy for large files on spotty/slow connection

Tags: java, download, upload, file-transfer

I'm having trouble researching strategies for uploading/downloading large files on a slow/spotty connection, where transfers are prone to fail.  We'd like to be able to resume an upload/download if and when it fails.

Can anyone point me to any existing strategies?  We are using Java--if there are any existing open source libraries in place, that would be a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

Stop rediscovering the wheel and use a protocol which already handles such cases.

E.g. [Apache's FTP client](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) with [Apache's FTP server](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/)?